# Colocar botones horizontalmente con bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, diseño

Buen dia,

Tengo 3 botones los cuales quiero que se me muestren en un navegador de escritorio como chrome, los 3 en linea horizontal pero no que salgan tan separados uno del otro ya que si aplico la clase col de separacion 4 para cada div que estan dentro del div row, se ponen en horizontal como quiero pero uno al lado izquierdo, el otro en el centro y el otro casi al extremo derecho.. que podria hacer para que aparezcan horizontalmente pero que esten separados ligeramente?

aqui dejo el codigo sin la modificacion 4 4 4, como esta el codigo me los muestra uno sobre el otro y en la parte web de un movil lo muestra tambien uno sobre el otro

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
          <button type="button" onclick='consultar()'>Solicitadas</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
          <button type="button" onclick='consultar2()'>Solicitadas</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
          <button type="button" onclick='consultar3()'>Solicitadas</button>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias utilizar css.  Si tienes otros divs con la clase col, puedes agregar otra clase a los divs que quieres separarar y usar esa clase nueva en el css en lugar de col.

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
          <button type="button" onclick='consultar()'>Solicitadas</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
          <button type="button" onclick='consultar2()'>Solicitadas</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
          <button type="button" onclick='consultar3()'>Solicitadas</button>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```